# How to put music in individual scenes and have it change when i select a new scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Alright I've managed to make an almost web page style thing in flash. I have all the coding to navigate the pages finished, but now I'm having the issue of when I change pages my main page music continues while the other pages music begins. I.,m unsure of how to code this. can anyone help? also I already have click sound effects going for my buttons and they seem to be working fine. Don't know if that helps at all. I'm also using flash cs6 and don't want to go to cc, because the removal of the bone tool.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a sound, you will need to use a SoundChannel object when you tell the sound to play. Then, with the reference to the SoundChannel, you can stop the sound before you exit the section.

```
// save this reference for later so you can stop the sound when you want..
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play(); // Get a sound channel. 
// Call this later
mySoundChannel.stop();
```

Without a SoundChannel to control it, the sound object will do its default behavior, which is to play to completion.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html